# Is my login function secure ? don't know how to improve it

Tags: php, function, cakephp, optimization

Using cakePHP, I would love to have your point of view about this small source code, i am not sure if its enought secure. `sha1()` will be removed with another hash script. I found it can be optimized but how ?

Thankyou

class UsersController extends Controller {

```
    function account($Req){
      if(isset($Req->post->login)){
           $login = addslashes($Req->post->login);
           $password = sha1(addslashes($Req->post->password));
           $pass_confirm = sha1(addslashes($Req->post->pass_confirm));
           $email = addslashes($Req->post->email);
           $signature = addslashes($Req->post->signature);

           if(empty($login) || empty($email)){
                $this->Session->setFlash("You hav to complete each fiedls", "error");
                            $this->Request->redirect(SITE . "users/account");
           }
           elseif($pass_confirm != $password) {
                            $this->Session->setFlash("You gave two differents password", "error");
                            $Req->redirect(SITE . "users/account");
                    }

            $this->loadModel("Users");

                    $dispoLogin = $this->Users->findCount(array(
                            "login" => $login
                    ));
                    if($dispoLogin === 0){
                            $this->Session->setFlash("The login is already use by someone else", "error");
                            $this->Request->redirect(SITE . "users/account");
                    }

           $dispoEmail = $this->Users->findCount(array(
                            "email" => $email
                    ));
                    if($dispoEmail === 0){
                            $this->Session->setFlash("Email adress already use by someone else", "error");
                            $this->Request->redirect(SITE . "users/account");
                    }

                    if(empty($password)){
                            $q = $this->Users->findFirst(array(
                                    "fields" => "password",
                                    "conditions" => array(
                                            "id" => $this->User->id
                                    )
                            ));
                            $password = sha1($q->password);
                    }

                    $this->Users->save(array(
                            "id" => $this->User->id,
                            "login" => $login,
                            "password" => $password,
                            "email" => $email,
                            "signature" => $signature
                    )); 
                    $this->user->setData(array(
                            "login" => $login,
                            "password" => $password,
                            "email" => $email,
                            "signature" => $signature
                    ));

                    $this->Session->setFlash("Your profile page is updated");
                    $this->Request->redirect(SITE);
      }
 }
```

Comment: This is a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com, voting to move there.

Comment: @JamWaffles Its not fit there either. http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mob Darn it! Got the two mixed up.

Comment: Thank you, do i hve to move there ?

Comment: @Zeroth: just edit, select all, copy; open other site, new question, type title, paste, submit

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5501/is-my-login-function-secure-how-to-improve-it

Answer (score 4):

Please read the [CakePHP Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/), preferably from the start because you really are getting a lot wrong here.

- There is no need to `addslashes()` everything, (or anything ever)
- CakePHP has it's own [AuthComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication), so no need to roll your own
- It also has a [validation engine](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1143/Data-Validation), so no need to validate anything here
- You're also passing some Request object to the method? I don't even want to ask...

This action should basically be about 6 lines long. TL;DR: Read the CakePHP Authentication docs, and start again.